# CSH - command in back quote lose all spaces and newlines

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

When I use `tcsh` to process a txt file, I meet a problem.
I have already processed the data, and stored the results in variable `temp`.

For the following command, it is used to sort the processed data and stores sorted data in a temp file. It can produce the correct result:

```
echo "$temp" | sort -t , -k1n -k2 >> tempsorted
```

However, due to some reason, I cannot use temp file. I need to redirect the results to variable. I tried the following command:

```
set a=`echo "$temp" | sort -t , -k1n -k2`
```

This command removes all the `space` and `newlines` in the results. Like this: `2739, Northville city, Wayne , Northville city | Wayne | 2739 2929, Village of Grosse Pointe Shores city, Wayne , Village of Grosse Pointe Shores city | Wayne | 2929 ...`

Anyone has idea about this? I need to store the sorted result in a variable to do extra processing without using temp file. Env should be `#!/bin/tcsh -f` Thanks.

### Part of content in `temp` variable:

```
84094, Westland city, Wayne , Westland city                        | Wayne          |      84094
28497, Northville township, Wayne , Northville township                  | Wayne          |      28497
17593, Wayne city, Wayne , Wayne city                           | Wayne          |      17593
27692, Garden City city, Wayne , Garden City city                     | Wayne          |      27692
3991, Belleville city, Wayne , Belleville city                      | Wayne          |       3991
3289, Rockwood city, Wayne , Rockwood city                        | Wayne          |       3289
```

### Part of expected result:

```
2739, Northville city, Wayne , Northville city                      | Wayne          |       2739
2929, Village of Grosse Pointe Shores city, Wayne , Village of Grosse Pointe Shores city | Wayne          |       2929
3289, Rockwood city, Wayne , Rockwood city                        | Wayne          |       3289
3991, Belleville city, Wayne , Belleville city                      | Wayne          |       3991
4656, Gibraltar city, Wayne , Gibraltar city                       | Wayne          |       4656
5421, Grosse Pointe city, Wayne , Grosse Pointe city                   | Wayne          |       5421
```

### Solutions I tried with error:

1.

```
set a=$("$temp" | sort -t , -k1n -k2)
```

has error message

```
Illegal variable name.
```

2.

```
set a="`"$temp" | sort -t , -k1n -k2`"
```

has error message

```
Unmatched `.
```

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [tcsh preserve newlines in command substitution \`…\`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284220/80273)

Comment: In #1, are you shure that shouldn't be `echo "$temp"`? Also, when you care checking the value of `$a`, do not forget to quote it `echo "$a"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I fill `echo "$temp" | sort -t , -k1n -k2` into `some command`, It gives "Unmatched `." Error.

Comment: put a "" around the `` is the right way. Have you tried ```set a="`echo $temp:q | sort -t , -k1n -k2`" ```?

Answer (score 0):

**``** is called Command substitution in tcsh. By default command substitution converts the entire output into "words" separated at spaces, tabs and newlines. I don't think that behavior can be changed. See the below simple example

```
> cat /tmp/file
lots           of spaces
line 2
> echo `cat /tmp/file`
lots of spaces line 2
>
```